# Symfony 3: What should I checkin to git?

Tags: php, symfony

I am new to Symfony 3 (earlier I worked with Yi 1 and now I want to try something new).

I am very confused, that the structure looks so much different - and the framework seems to be mixed up with the application logic.

What would I now checkin into git? Of course I dont want to have the framework in git, only my application (config, php, templates, ...).

```
\app
\bin
\src
\tests
\var *
\vendor *
\web
composer.json
```

Should everything be checked in but "var" and "vendor"? Is this, where the framework-core is in?

Also, I found an example app for symfony, but it is for symfony 2.7 - does anyone knows, if there is a example app for the new symfony 3?

Comment: The demo application right now is only updated to use Symfony 2.8. But you can use the installer to set up an application based on the Symfony Standard Edition which comes with a ready to use `gitignore` file.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do not commit the following:

```
/app/config/parameters.yml
/build/
/phpunit.xml
/var/*
!/var/cache
/var/cache/*
!var/cache/.gitkeep
!/var/logs
/var/logs/*
!var/logs/.gitkeep
!/var/sessions
/var/sessions/*
!var/sessions/.gitkeep
!var/SymfonyRequirements.php
/vendor/
/web/bundles/
```

Everything else can be committed.

Comment: does this help? @TSM

Comment: Thank you very much - this helps a lot! Only thing I do not understand is, why do you write "!/var/logs" and then "/var/logs/*"? What does that mean? Thank you again!

Comment: It mean you will commit the var/logs/ dir, but not it's content. Like, except (! as "different" or "not") /var/logs, and all var/logs/*